# Guardar Imagem no Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, imagem, base64

No meu sistema existe um cadastro de Profissional que tem a opção de salvar a foto do Profissional também, no momento eu estou fazendo uma conversão da foto para `Base64` com `Javascript` no `front-end` e mandando pro `back-end` que converte para `byte[]` e guarda no Banco de Dados em uma coluna do tipo `bytea`.

No momento estou estudando todo esse fluxo e percebi que isto deixa o sistema meio lento pois, por exemplo, uma requisição do `front-end` para o `back-end` para obter uma lista de Profissionais acaba sendo lenta pois o `JSON` que vem do `back-end` é muito grande por causa das fotos em `Base64`.

Alguem tem alguma idéia que possa me ajudar a deixar esse fluxo mais rapido, algum outro tipo de conversão da imagem em vez de `Base64` para que o `JSON` não fique tão pesado, ou algum outro tipo de conversão que posso fazer no meu `back-end` para guardar no banco.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Meu `Back-end` é em `Java` com o framework `Spring Boot`.
Meu `Front-end` é em `Angular 7` então usa `Typescript/Javascript`.
Meu `Banco de Dados` é em `PostgreSQL`

Comment: Quando se trata de salvamento de imagem, o mais viável é vc salvar a imagem em um diretório no servidor e salvar no banco apenas uma referência para aquela imagem. Salvamento de imagem no banco só torna a aplicação mais lenta  para responder.

Comment: O front-end sempre espera que os Profissionais venham com informação de foto ou só em casos específicos?

Comment: @Jorge.M eu sei disso mas no planejamento do sistema que estou trabalhando eles decidiram que não daria pra fazer isto.

Comment: @ArthurFerraz eu ja entendi oque vc quis dizer e sim eu ja estou trabalhando nisso desde semana passada, estou fazendo com que a foto venha apenas em requisições q realmente vão usar ela, mas eu ainda estou em busca de uma solução pro meu problema, conversões melhores para guardar a imagem no banco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O banco de dados é bom para lidar com **dados**, como tabelas com diversas colunas e informações. Sistemas de arquivos são bons para lidar com **arquivos**, como imagens de diversos tamanhos e documentos.

## Guardando em um servidor de arquivos

Se você tem muitas imagens ou o servidor tem muitas requisições que lidem com as imagens, use um serviço de hospedagem de imagens, como Amazon S3 ou Google Cloud Storage. Essa solução é boa porque:

- Seu banco de dados irá salvar somente um referência para essa imagem e não a imagem inteira. Exemplo: `imagens.host.com/bruno/imagem123.png`.
- O front-end não irá mais converter a foto de base 64 para imagem, e sim, somente carregá-la de um servidor HTTP.
- As imagens terão caching, provido pelo navegador e pelo hosting de imagens.
- Menos banda sendo trafegada durante os requests.
- O front-end vai conseguir montar a página inteira, com todas as informações relevantes vindas do back-end, e as imagens podem ser carregadas posteriormente. Isso aumenta seu score de SEO e performance, no quesito First Meaningful Paint.

Se for optar por essa solução, você pode também utilizar uma ferramenta para cortar as imagens em diversos tamanhos, assim você teria vários tamanhos de uma mesma imagem, prezando pela performance da requisição HTTP dependendo da velocidade da conexão do cliente. É por isso que às vezes o Facebook, por exemplo, nos entrega imagens menores (ou seja, de qualidade inferior) quando estamos em uma internet mais lenta. Uma das ferramentas mais utilizadas para isso é o ImageMagick, que tem um [wrapper para Java](https://github.com/techblue/jmagick).

## Guardando no banco de dados

Se ainda sim, visto tantas vantagens de guardar as imagens em um servidor externo, que foi feito para arquivos, você quer guardá-las no seu banco de dados, tenha em mente:

- O banco de dados pode crescer muito rápido se você guarda suas imagens nele, diminuindo sua performance de escrita e leitura
- Não existem muitas vantagens, visto que não há indexação, busca, ou joins nesse tipo de coluna

A solução seria utilizar o tipo [`blob`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/jdbc-binary-data.html), disponível no PostgreSQL.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta.